# simulate on low memory warning

Tags: android

I have `override` following method

```
 @Override
    public void onLowMemory() 
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Log.i("AboutView Fragment","OnLowMemory invoked");
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
```

but this method doesn't called ,how to simulate low memory warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on why do you need it. For example, you can call it directly.

```
yourAppInstance.onLowMemory();
```

And check that you do something to free some memory.

Or you can fill up memory by creating a lot of data (e.g., while(not_called) {list.add(new byte[1024]);}) and wait for onLowMemory to be called. Then delete created data (list.clear()).